# list index out of range(sometimes fails sometimes works)

Tags: python

I'm reading datas from a file. content: time-id-data,
when I run on MAC, it works well, but on linux, sometimes it works sometimes fails. 
the error is "IndexError: list index out of range"
data like this:

[image]

'
1554196690  0.0 178 180 180 178 178 178 180

1554196690  0.1 178 180 178 180 180 178 178

1554196690  0.2 175 171 178 173 173 178 172

1554196690  0.3 171 175 175 17b 179 177 17e

1554196691  0.4 0   d3

1554196691  0.50    28:10:4:92:a:0:0:d6     395

1554196691  0.58    28:a2:23:93:a:0:0:99        385
'

```
data = []
boardID=100 #how many lines at most in datafile
for i in range(8):
    data.append([[] for x in range(8)])#5 boards,every boards have 7 sensors add 1-boardID

time_stamp = []
time_xlabel=[]
time_second=[]
for i in range(8):
    time_stamp.append([]) #5th-lines data is the input voltage and pressure
    time_xlabel.append([])#for x label
    time_second.append([])#time from timestamp to time(start-time is 0)

with open("Potting_20190402-111807.txt","r") as eboardfile:
    for line in eboardfile:
        values = line.strip().split("\t")
        boardID=int(round(float(values[1])%1*10)) #define board, 0-3 is the electronBoards, board4-pressure sensor, board5-temperature sensor located inside house not on eboard.
        time_stamp[boardID].append(int(values[0]))

        if boardID >= 0 and boardID < 4:
            for i in range(2,9):
                data[boardID][i-2].append(int(values[i],16) * 0.0625)

        if boardID==4:#pressure
            data[boardID][0].append( int(values[2],16) * 5./1024. *14.2/2.2)            #voltage divider: 12k + 2.2k
            data[boardID][1].append( (int(values[3],16) * 5./1024. - 0.5) / 4.*6.9*1000.)      #adc to volt: value * 5V/1024, volt to hpa: (Vout - 0.5V)/4V *6.9bar * 1000i

        elif boardID > 4 and boardID < 7: #temperature sensor located inside house not no electronBoards
            data[boardID][0].append(int(values[4],10) * 0.0625)#values[2] is the address,[3]-empty;[4]is the valueself.
eboardfile.close()
```

---

```
 Traceback(most recent call last):
      boardID=int(round(float(values[1])%1*10)) #define board, 0-3 is the electronBoards, board4-pressure sensor, board5-temperature sensor located inside house not on eboard.
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What dou you want to achive in this row : `boardID=int(round(float(values[1])%1*10))`? Bc. after applying `%1` you allready get a whole number, there is no need to round further. Also when applying `int()` on a float, you cut off the decimals. So you can use `int(float(value[1]))*10` which is more readable

Answer (score 0):

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
      boardID=int(round(float(values[1])%1*10)) #define board, 0-3 is the electronBoards, board4-pressure sensor, board5-temperature sensor located inside house not on eboard.
IndexError: list index out of range
```

this error occurs when your `values` has element less than one, which means `values = line.strip().split("\t")`, the `line` has no `\t` at all.

maybe a empty line? or linux format problem.

you can check the `len` of `values` before use:

```
if len(values) < 9:
    continue
```

or try this:

```
import string
values = line.strip().split(string.whitespace)
```

can not reproduce your condition, so just have a try.